# Newline in command line argument in tcsh

Tags: command-line, tcsh, newlines

In bash, it is easy to pass newline as command line argument:

```
foo 'this is 
a command line argument
with newlines'
```

However, if I try the same in tcsh, it complains about a missing `'`. How can I type the same in tcsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'this has\
more than one line'
```